# Play sound in Win32 program using MinGW + Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, winapi, c++11, mingw

As you can see from the title I am using MinGW and Eclipse to make a Win32 application that plays a sound from its own resources. I am new to this MinGW compiler and Eclipse, and my C++ is a little rusty. Using VC++ is not an option at the moment.

So, As far as I can understand, I have trouble adding some library stuff to the application.

My code goes as follows

```
//MyClass.cpp

#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"libwinmm.a")

#include "MyClass.h"
#include "../resources.h"

/*------------------------------------*/

void MyClass::Enable() {
    _isEnabled = true;
    PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(ActivatedSound), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_ASYNC);
}

//resources.h

#define ActivatedSound 2001

//resources.rc

ActivatedSound WAVE "resources/sounds/activated.wav"
```

Compiler options: -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11

Linker flags: -mwindows

I'm getting the error in the line where I call the PlaySound function.

Error: undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong, and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

It seem that I have fixed my problem by adding a record containing "winmm" to the Libraries field under Project Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2N8f.png

... and of course removing the #pragma statement also helped.

Comment: You used a Visual Studio specific `#pragma` but failed to use Visual Studio. Either use Visual Studio, or replace the `#pragma` with the appropriate linker flag `-lwinmm`. See [Specify the libraries for the linker to use](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use) for reference.

Comment: I remove the pragma statement and added -lwinmm to the linker flags. But didn't seem to help. Same error occurs.
My linker flags look like this: -mwindows -lwinmm

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the **order** as outlined in the link I posted above?

Comment: I didn't follow the instructions on the order. But it did push me into the right direction. I remembered that there are two fields in Eclipse containing libraries and library paths. And since winmm is a basic library it was enough to specify the library name in the library list.
Thanks a lot for the article, mate.

Comment: Unrelated, but worth noting: MinGW/Eclipse use poor default settings. You are compiling an ANSI version of your application. Windows natively uses UNICODE character encoding and you should compile a UNICODE application as well (for many reasons). Make sure to `#define` both `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` and remove the `MBCS` preprocessor symbol, if present.

Comment: I did some research on UNICODE, and I will definitely use it for my application. Thanks again, mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was not specifying the library I was trying to use (-lwinmm) in the proper field.
So, instead of putting it in the linker flags, I had to add it to the library list (duh..).

In Eclipse (Kepler) this list in located under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries, then click on the add button and type in *winmm* without the *-l*

Here is a screenshot that shows what it should look like, in case I wasn't specific enough:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GCC does not understand VS linker pragma's. This means adding

```
-lwinmm
```

to the linker flags yourself, like with any other compiler.

Comment: I remove the pragma statement and added -lwinmm to the linker flags. But didn't seem to help. Same error occurs.